# float object has no attribute __getitem__

Tags: python, types, pygame

This is the error I'm getting from this function:

```
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The `self.target` is just an tuple and `self.x` and `self.y` are ints, I don't know what I've done wrong.

```
class Robot(object):
def __init__(self):
    global WIDTH
    global HEIGHT
    global BACKGROUND
    self.speed = random.randint(0,8)
    self.size = 5
    self.counter = 0
    self.direction = "n"
    self.target = (0,0)
    self.directions = ["n","ne","e","se","s","sw","w","nw","stop"]
    self.distance_to_cords = {}
    self.target_cords = []

    self.direction_movementsy = {"n": -1,
                                "ne" : -1,
                                "e" : 0,
                                "se" : 1,
                                "s": 1,
                                "sw": 1,
                                "w": 0,
                                "nw": -1}

    self.direction_movementsx = {"n": 0,
                                "ne" : 1,
                                "e" : 1,
                                "se" : 1,
                                "s": 0,
                                "sw": -1,
                                "w": -1,
                                "nw": -1}







    self.x = random.randint(0,WIDTH)
    self.y = random.randint(0,HEIGHT)
    self.colour = RED

def draw(self):
    pygame.draw.polygon(DISPLAYSURF,self.colour,((self.x,self.y),(self.x,self.y + self.size ),(self.x + self.size,self.y + self.size),(self.x + self.size,self.y)))
    pygame.display.update()

def undraw(self):
    pygame.draw.polygon(DISPLAYSURF,BACKGROUND,((self.x,self.y),(self.x,self.y + self.size ),(self.x + self.size,self.y + self.size),(self.x + self.size,self.y)))
    pygame.display.update()

def direction_decider(self):
    #x stuff

    #w
    if self.target[0] < self.x:
        question1 = True
    else:
        question1 = False

    #e
    if self.target[0] > self.x:
        question2 = True
    else:
        question2 = False


    #n
    if self.target[0] < self.y: 
        question3 = True
    else:
        question3 = False

    #s
    if self.target[0] > self.y:
        question4 = True
    else:
        question4 = False


    answer = (question1, question2, question3, question4)


    lookup_which_direct = { (True,False,False,False):"w",
                            (False,True,False,False):"e",
                            (False,False,True,False):"n",
                            (False,False,False,True):"s",
                            (True,False,True,False):"nw",
                            (True,False,False,True):"sw",
                            (False,True,True,False):"ne",
                            (False,True,False,True):"se"}

    cheese =lookup_which_direct[answer]
    print cheese












def dist_calc(self):
    for p in plant_list:
        x_dist = self.x - p.x
        y_dist = self.y - p.y
        total_dist = (y_dist**2 +x_dist**2)**0.5
        self.distance_to_cords[total_dist] = (p.x,p.y)
    ordering_list = self.distance_to_cords.keys()
    ordering_list = sorted(ordering_list)
    self.target = ordering_list[0]
    self.target_cords = self.distance_to_cords[self.target]
```

Comment: And what is `self.target` then? My first thought is that *that* must be the `float` value here. What is the full traceback?

Comment: Why don't you show the **full** traceback of the error? If the failure is with `self.target` then how are we supposed to know why it is failing if you do not show where it is defined(and: no, it isn't a tuple if you get an error). (Side note: instead of `if condition: questionX = True else questionX = False` simply do `questionX = condition`, or `not condition` if you want the negation.)

Comment: hang on excuse me, ill post all my code

Comment: From a quick look, it seems `self.target` is a `float` and `self.target_cords` is a tuple. Maybe you want to use the latter where you are using the former.

Comment: I do not understand why you have selected any answers for your questions. These people are trying to help with your issues. Please explain to them if something is still missing. You have got upvoted answers as well, so your action is kinda weird if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

You set `self.target` to a `float` in `dist_calc`:

```
for p in plant_list:
    x_dist = self.x - p.x
    y_dist = self.y - p.y
    total_dist = (y_dist**2 +x_dist**2)**0.5
    self.distance_to_cords[total_dist] = (p.x,p.y)
ordering_list = self.distance_to_cords.keys()
ordering_list = sorted(ordering_list)
self.target = ordering_list[0]
```

Here `ordering_list` is a sequence of floating point values (the `total_dist` values), and you set `self.target` to the lowest value of these (you could have used `min(self.distance_to_cords)` there instead of sorting).

Perhaps you meant to set it to `self.distance_to_cords[min(self.distance_to_cords)]` instead?

Answer (score 0):

`self.target` has become a `float` somehow.

Perhaps something like `self.target = self.target[0]` happened somewhere in your code?

Either that, or `self.target = some_variable_that_is_a_float`

Answer (score 0):

```
total_dist = (y_dist**2 +x_dist**2)**0.5
```

This will be a `float` for most integer values of `x_dist` and `y_dist`.

```
self.distance_to_cords[total_dist] = (p.x,p.y)
```

Now `self.distance_to_cords` has a probable `float` key.

```
ordering_list = self.distance_to_cords.keys()
ordering_list = sorted(ordering_list)
```

Now `ordering_list` is a `list` of mixed `float`s and (occasionally) `int`s.

```
self.target = ordering_list[0]
```

Now `self.target` is probably a `float`, which means that your `direction_decider` would likely raise the exception you stated if called after your code at the bottom runs.